# Error (traceback) al traer datos de api

Tags: python, firebase, api, flask

Actualmente tengo este código

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/listar'
payload = {"cc": 1046}
headers = {'Conten-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, json = payload, headers = headers)
h = response.headers
server = h['server']

if response.status_code == 200:
    res = response.json()
    print(res)#trae todos los datos del usuario por su 'cc'
    for aux in res:
        apellido = aux['apellido1']
        nombre = aux['nombre1']
        print(apellido +' '+nombre)
```

Mi objetivo es guardar en una variable el nombre y el apellido, como muestra en el bucle for, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
ramirez martha 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 20, in <module>
    apellido = aux['apellido1']
KeyError: 'apellido1'
```

Me muestra el nombre y apellido pero me dice que tengo un error en la linea donde busco 'apellido1'

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal y como lo puedo corregir?

NOTA: la api la cree yo conectada a firebase.

Gracias

Comment: Intentas acceder a la key apellido pero `aux` no es un diccionario sino una cadena de texto. Ejecuta antes `type(res)` a ver qué dice. Puedes intentar cargarlo de vuelta como un diccionario antes del for con `d = json.loads(res)` y loopear si lo necesitas

Comment: Si usas  Python 3.6+ es mejor que uses la cadena `f` para imprimir texto, es más intuitiva y cómoda cuando le coges (bastante rápido) el truco. En lugar de `print(apellido + ' '+nombre)` usa `f'{apellido} {nombre}'`

Comment: Jose Rodriguez gracias por tus comentarios. efectivamente ejecute el type(res) y me dice que es un tipo 'list'  pero a ejecutar json.loads(res) sale un error al cargarlo como diccionario.

y estoy usando python 3.6 pero sale un error cunado ejecuto f'{apellido} {nombre}'
quedo pendiente a tus comentario!!

Comment: Hola Alberto, haz `print(repr(res))` y muestra que te imprime. El JSON en principio es una **lista de diccionarios**, por el error (`aux` debe ser un diccionario, `KeyError` al indizar no lo puede generar una cadena, lista, etc) ya que es un error que indica que la clave no se encuentra en el diccionario. Si la API es tuya sería bueno ver como generas el JSON de respuesta.

Comment: FjSevilla gracias por tu comentario.
esto imprime el JSON:
<class 'list'>
[{'apellido1': 'ramirez', 'apellido2': 'perez', 'cc': 1046, 'correo': 'martha@gmail.com', 'createdAt': '"2019-08-20 08:39:30.311506"', 'edad': "'35'", 'estadocivil': 'casada', 'fechanacimiento': '1985-09-17', 'genero': 'mujer', 'nombre1': 'martha', 'nombre2': 'helena'}, {'celular': '3025698854', 'telefono': '3289547'}, {'direccion': 'calle 26 # 89-65', 'estrato': '3', 'fechavivio': '2010-11-26'}]

Comment: Vale, eso confirma mi sospecha... El JSON lo construyes mal en la API en principio, fijate que los datos para un mismo usuario (supongo) están repartidos en 3 diccionarios, dos de ellos no deberían existir por separado en principio `{'celular': '3025698854', 'telefono': '3289547'}` y `{'direccion': 'calle 26 # 89-65', 'estrato': '3', 'fechavivio': '2010-11-26'}` no tienen la clave `"apellido1"`  por eso el error. En principio estos tres diccionarios deberían formar uno solo, o en todo caso estar dentro de una lista los tres.

Comment: Para ese JSON podrías obtener tus datos mediante  `apellido = res[0]['apellido1']` y `nombre = res[0]['nombre1']` pero que esto funcione siempre depende de como generes el JSON (el diccionario con el nombre debe estar siempre en el primer índice de la lista) y de si retornas más de un usuario en una misma consulta.

Comment: Disculpa albertomartinez, he estado revisando el código y está bien escrito, pero como dice @FJSevilla la estructura es extraña y tu código asume que tu respuesta json tenga siempre las mismas keys. La solución es cambiar el json que mandas o cambiar tu loop.

Comment: En la API, si por lo que sea tienes los datos inicialmente separados en tres diccionarios, lo suyo es por cada usuario unirlos, por ejemplo con `usr = {**a, **b, **c}` dónde `a`, `b` y `c` sería esos tres diccionarios. Luego si la consulta puede retornar varios usuarios, metes cada dict `usr` en una lista `[usr1, usr2, ...]` y eso constituiría tu JSON. Si se retorna un solo usuario siempre genera el JSON a partir de `usr` simplemente y no uses una lista.

Comment: Como último comentario me estaba rayando con la etiqueta [flask] que has puesto a tu pregunta y pensaba que `requests` era un error porque el modulo de flask se llama `request` en singular y no entendía como el código te funcionaba...excepto si usas el modulo `requests` de python. Mi pregunta ahora es: ¿dónde usas flask?

Comment: FjSevilla gracias por tus comentarios, efectivamente esa era la solución, cambie la forma como estaba generando mi JSON, ahora me queda de esta forma {'cc': 1046, 'nombre1': 'martha', 'nombre2': 'helena', 'apellido1': 'ramirez', 'apellido2': 'perez', 'edad': "'35'", 'correo': 'martha@gmail.com', 'fechanacimiento': '1985-09-17', 'estadocivil': 'casada', 'genero': 'mujer', 'createdAt': '"2019-08-20 08:39:30.311506"', 'celuar0': '3025698854', 'telefono0': '3289547', 'direccion0': 'calle 26 # 89-65', 'estrato0': '3', 'fechavivio0': '2010-11-26'}
ya puedo acceder a los datos, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Jose Rodriguez gracias por tus cometarios, soy nuevo en python asi que uso el framework de flask para la creacion de pagina mas rapido(me lo recomendo un amigo),
pero para comsumir una api segui este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD_gvyH8tLU donde usan el requests que viene de python y no el request que es de flask.
tambien me enrede al principio jaja, espero te halla aclarado la duda, gracias por la ayuda . feliz dia